# how to get a zig zag pattern between two array?

Tags: python-3.x, list, data-structures

I am trying to find the zig zag pattern between two arrays. I've come across posts where 1 array is used. I understand the logic of it but even when i append the two lists together, I am unable to get the desired output.

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
expected_output = [5,9,3,7,1,6,2,8,4,10]
```

any hint to solve it would help. P.S I am still learning programming, so if i missed an obvious pattern, do let me know. thanks!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried? I could dump a solution using iterators, but I doubt that would help you. Do not try to copy someone else's solution - you won't learn anything at all that way. Instead, try to write your own code.

Comment: Here are two simpler problems that can set you on the right path. (Problem 1) Given one list, return the zigzag pattern on that list; for instance, [1,2,3,4,5] should give [5, 3, 1, 4, 2]. (Problem 2) Given two lists, return the alternating pattern on those two lists: for instance, [1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10] should give [5,10,4,9,3,8,2,7,1,6].